# Commands available in bash -i can't access in bash -l

Tags: linux, bash, shell, vim, terminal

I don't know how to describe it. It just happens when i use vim and `set shell=bash -l`. Then i found that a command called `mm` which can execute in terminal can't execute in vim .

And i also found that when i write this command in `run.sh` and execute this script. It still report `command not found`. I think there must be something wrong with my `$HOME/.bash*` files  and `$HOME/.profile`. And i am sure that `.profile` are almost the same with `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `$ man bash`:

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a
>   non-interactive shell  with  the --login  option,  it  first  reads
>   and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.
>   After reading that file, it  looks  for  ~/.bash_profile, 
>   ~/.bash_login,  and ~/.profile,  in  that  order, and **reads and
>   executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.**

and

> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash
>   reads and executes commands  from  ~/.bashrc,  if  that  file  exists.

So:

```
shell   | files loaded    
--------+-----------------
bash -l | /etc/profile    
        | ~/.bash_profile 
        | ~/.bash_login
        | ~/.profile     
--------+-----------------
bash -i | ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Note, though, that bash -l will stop after loading the first of the user configuration files. It is customary to set up `.bash_profile` to load `.bashrc` and `.profile` in turn, but this does not happen unless it's explicitly configured that way.

Comment: Yes, I've bolded the relevant part.